# A MAC address is a string of zeros. Why?

Tags: networking, hardware, ifconfig

When I execute:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/*/address
```

I get:

```
f4:b5:20:23:9a:a4
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The 1st is my ethernet MAC address, and the 2nd is, I guess (I'm not an expert on those things), my computer's MAC address. The computer works fine despite this all-zero address. However, I am having trouble to register a software online, because the registration process requires a "real" MAC address and an all-zero address is not acceptable.

Why is that and what should I do (if anything)?

Ubuntu 20.04 (Xfce) 64-bit.

Thanks.

Comment: It's normal and expected output. The top one is your ethernet address. The bottom one is your loopback address. Try `ip addr` to see which MAC address maps to which interface.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for your reply. The command you suggested spat a lot of stuff I cannot understand:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000

    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 

       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
`
"2:" refers to the ethernet, and I won't post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Your are throwing out useful information with your method. Information which tells you which interface corresponds to which MAC address. Do this instead:

```
~$ grep . /sys/class/net/*/address
/sys/class/net/enp2s0/address:00:19:b9:0d:af:fa
/sys/class/net/enp4s0/address:00:22:b0:75:c2:bd
/sys/class/net/lo/address:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

And therefore we observe that is the local loopback interface, lo, with the all 0's MAC address.